# map enqueue in backend

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I enqueued a script like google-map.

I enqueued in front-end and this works well. (I edited my key in url)

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_fn');
function enqueue_fn(){
    wp_register_script( 'daum_map_api', '//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=THIS PART IS MY KEY&libraries=services', null, null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'daum_map_api' );
}
```

But when I enqueued it in wp-admin, it generates errors.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue' );
function admin_enqueue(){
   wp_register_script( 'daum_map_api', 'https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=THIS PART IS MY KEY&libraries=services' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'daum_map_api' );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I found somethig. '&' this character changes like this ';' in url.  how can I put the '&' character in there?

Comment: '&amp;' instead of '&' also changes to  ';'

Comment: Are both your frontend and your backend running via https? Is the API key identical?

Comment: I am developing this site in localhost, now. And api key is correct. what does it meant that running via https? sorry.